# Second AJAX function fails when other AJAX function has already been executed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a file that shows a bunch of orders, each of which has a button with an ajax function that sends an email. Aside from that, every 30 seconds another ajax function runs and searches for new orders and loads them on top. When I first load the page, the send mail function works just fine. But once the function that searches for new orders has been executed for the first time, when I click the button that fires the mail ajax function, it doesn't send it and reloads the page

I have checked for repeated variable and function names that might conflict but there's none. The functions work just fine on their own, only when the order-searching one has been executed the other one starts to fail

this is the simplified html code for each form (there are many orders on the page with different ids)

```
<form role="form" id="contactForm4081">
    <div class="form-group fg4081">
        <label for="message" class="h4 ">Tiempo de entrega</label>
        <!--  <textarea id="message" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your message" required></textarea> -->
        <input type="hidden" value="Santiago" name="name4081" id="name4081" />
        <input type="hidden" value="contacto@nodorojo.com" name="email4081" id="email4081" />
        <select name="message4081" id="message4081" required>
            <option value="15">15 min</option>
            <option value="30">30 min</option>
            <option value="45">45 min</option>
            <option value="60">60 min</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="btn btn-default btn-md pull-right ">Enviar mail</button>
    </div>

    <div id="msgSubmit4081" class="h4 text-center hidden">Tiempo de entrega enviado.</div>
</form>
```

this is the mail function

```
$("#contactForm4081").submit(function(event){
    // cancels the form submission
    event.preventDefault();
    submitForm4081();
});
  function submitForm4081(){
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var name4081 = $("#name4081").val();
    var email4081 = $("#email4081").val();
    var message4081 = $("#message4081").val();
 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/process.php",
        data: "name=" + name4081 + "&email=" + email4081 + "&message=" + message4081,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess4081();
            }
        }
    });
}
function formSuccess4081(){
    $( "#msgSubmit4081" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
    $( ".fg4081" ).addClass( "hidden" );
}
```

and this is the function that looks for new orders

```
var ultimoid = 4081;
var xultimoid = "";

  function nuevospedidos() {
     var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "cosito3.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
     console.log(response);
    var element = document.querySelector('#contenidogral');
    var content = element.innerHTML;
    ultimoid = response.ultimoid;
    element.innerHTML = response.contenido + content;
    }
  };
  xhttp.send("ultimoid="+encodeURIComponent(ultimoid));

  }
setInterval( nuevospedidos, 30000);
```

Comment: What is inside #contenidogral?

Comment: its the container to which the function adds the new found orders on top. it holds all the other orders with the same structure as this one but all the info and unique ids for each. nothing fancy

Comment: Is there are reason why you are mixing up jQuery ajax and native XMLHttpRequest object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of -

`$("#contactForm4081").submit(function(event){
    // cancels the form submission
    event.preventDefault();
    submitForm4081();
});`

Try with this -

```
 $(document).on("submit","#contactForm4081",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    submitForm4081();
});
```

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you! do you know the reason why this way it doesnt conflict?